# Correct way to do a string replace with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am a newbie to regex and my expression appears to be backwards or opposite of what I am trying to do.  I have a string, in this case a url, and I basically want to replace everything up to and including the last forward slash with an empty string. Currently I have

```
"http://www.sweet.com/member/other".replace(/[^/]+$/, "")
```

which basically does the opposite of what I want. What is the proper expression to get the results I'm seeking? Which in this case would be to end up with a string "other"? Thanks for any help

[RegExr example](http://regexr.com?34s66)

Comment: As I don't like regex (mostly because I'm not good at it), I would not use it in that case and simply split the string and take the last index of the resulting array, which will contain the result you expect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a regex that matches the beginning of the string, followed by as many characters as possible, followed by a slash:

```
/^.*\//
```

Comment: My down vote was not intentional, but it's locked in unless something changes, sorry :(

Answer (score 5):

[You don't even need RegExp for this](http://jsfiddle.net/cmhbx/). You just need the position of the last `/` and cut the string starting just after it.

```
var str = "http://www.sweet.com/member/other";

var other = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

You could also do splitting by `/` and get the last entry in the resulting array, but string manipulation is way faster most of the time.

Comment: I like non regex solutions where possible, +1. Though I would probably avoid using ´substr´ (not part of any ECMA standard) and use either ´substring´ or ´slice´ instead

Comment: Thanks, yes I was aware I could do it this way, I was more or less trying to understand regex expression is all. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

## This

Going with your original logic of using a replacement

`"http://www.sweet.com/member/other".replace(/^.*[\/]/, "")`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="demo">http://www.sweet.com/member/other</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var re=/^.*[\/]/
var str=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(re, '');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

## OR

`^(?:.*/)(.*?)$`

and pulling the value from the first group match

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I basically want to replace everything up to **and including** the last forward slash"

Comment: Yeah I misread the question. I've updated the response to match.

Comment: this is not correct either, it is missing an escape for the slash, "/(.*)(?=\/)/", and even then the result is "/other". http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/g4TzY/

Comment: Your correction now works, though you should still escape the slash so that it does not get misinterpreted by the JS engine (/^.*[\/]/) and there is no need for the "i" flag in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 other solutions (same as `/^.*\//`), if you like to avoid errors in jslint

```
console.log("http://www.sweet.com/member/other".replace(/^[\S\s]*\//, ""));
console.log("http://www.sweet.com/member/other".replace(new RegExp("\.*\\/"), ""));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ukVrn/)

And just to offer another method that does not require regex

```
console.log("http://www.sweet.com/member/other".split("/").slice(-1)[0]);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4yREJ/)